# Logparser query to get cookie value

Tags: sql, cookies, logparser

I have `abc=1234` added to cookie.

It shows up in IIS log. But the `cs`(Cookie) field shows other cookies also separated by semicolon.

I want to use [logparser](/questions/tagged/logparser) to get the value of cookie `abc`.

Can you please suggest a query?

e.g. if cs(Cookie) has value `+pqr=999;+abc=1234;+xyz=222`, the logparser query should return `1234`.

Answer (score 6):

Found it.
Use the extract_value() function

```
logparser "SELECT extract_value(cs(Cookie),'+abc',';') as abc_value from ..."
```

Comment: Very good, but the first cookie is not preceded by a `+` so would be missed. Given this, `coalesce(extract_value(cs(Cookie), 'abc', ';'), extract_value(cs(Cookie), '+abc', ';')) as abc_value` will find the value, even if it's first in the list. +1 anyway. Thx.